# Is there any difference in meaning and usage between "play along with someone" and "humor someone"?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning and usage between *play along with someone* and *humor someone* in the sense of pretending to agree with someone? For example:

> The boss strongly believes that the project will definitely fly. I wasn't sure about that, but I wouldn't have explained why, so I just **played along with** him.
>
> The boss strongly believes that the project will definitely fly. I wasn't sure about that, but I wouldn't have explained why, so I just **humored** him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you play along with someone whose idea isn't necessarily the best but it may work out. This means that you carry out the required actions and at least try.

On the other hand you humour someone whose ideas are clearly deluded. You probably won't want to play along.

**Examples**

> Q: My boss believes he can fly by flapping his arms, should I humour
> him?
>
> A: Only to a certain extent otherwise he may jump out of a window. Try
> to convince him that, although he may be right, this is not a good time to test the idea.

versus

> Q: My boss believes he can fly by flapping his arms, should I play
> along with him?
>
> A: No! If you play along, you both may end up jumping out of the
> window!